# How to concat 2 numeric fields and convert to string at the same time in SQL server SELECT

Tags: sql-server, select, string-concatenation

I have a table with 2 numeric fields: groupID and itemID.
Assume groupID is less than 2 digits in length and itemID less than 3 digits, I want to do this operation:

```
Select stringID = groupID (converted to 2-char string) concat itemID (converted to 3-char string) from ...
```

Of course, the code above just shows my intention and is not valid SQL code.
Example: if groupID is 2 and itemID is 34, I want stringID to be "02034".
If groupID is 23 and itemID is 6, I want stringID to be "23006".

Is it possible to do BOTH the conversion from numeric to string AND the string concatenation in the select statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you looking for this?

```
SELECT
     RIGHT('00' + CAST(groupID as varchar(2)), 2) +
     RIGHT('000' + CAST(itemID as varchar(3)), 3) as stringID FROM tbl
```